# How to check if a file has been opened by another application in C++?

Tags: c++, linux, file-io, process

I know, that there's the `is_open()` function in C++, but I want one program to check if a file hasn't been opened by another application. Is there any way to do it using standard library?

EDIT - Clarified in the answers that this is for a Linux application.

Answer (score 5):

Not only the standard library does not have this funcionality, it's not even possible in general. You could (on linux) check `/proc/*/fd` — but it is possible that your program does not have permission to do it on processes from other users (this is the default in Ubuntu, for instance).

Comment: 'not even possible in general' is not entirely true, see fuser program

Comment: I think you cannot use fuser without sudo to know if another process is accessing the file, can you? @Waslap

Answer (score 4):

No, the standard library has no such functionality.

Answer (score 3):

If you control the other process (have source code), the best plan is to use advisory locks in both processes. This locking is defined in POSIX, and will be portable across operating systems.

In Linux, you can use the utility [lsof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lsof) to see what files are opened by other processes.

This is limited to what you have permissions for - you have to do the check as a privileged user, or you'll only get results for files opened by the same user as the one doing the check.

I only know of the command line utility, not of any system call you can use directly from C code.

In Linux, it's also possible to turn on [mandatory locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking#File_locking_in_UNIX) for a given filesystem (mount -o mand), and set special flags on the file (chmod g-x,g+s).  Then when your process attempts to acquire a write lock, it will fail if another process has the file open. This is hardly ever used, but if you completely control the system in question, it may be an option.

Comment: I tried looking at the lsof source code one time to see how they did it and my head almost exploded. The source to lsof is an web of insanity and black magic.

Comment: I'd suggest using fuser over lsof.  Parsing the results will be much simpler.

Answer (score 3):

The following code may work.

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
    if (fd < 0) {
        perror("open");
        return 1;
    }

    if (fcntl(fd, F_SETLEASE, F_WRLCK) && EAGAIN == errno) {
        puts("file has been opened");
    }
    else {
        fcntl(fd, F_SETLEASE, F_UNLCK);
        puts("file has not been opened");
    }

    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In my case, this example always returns 'file has not been opened' even though file is opened. ```ls -al /proc/21862/fd/47
l-wx------ 1 user user 64  1월 29 17:12 /proc/21862/fd/47 -> /home/user/data/201802201020.mp4```. (Ubuntu)

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Perhaps you could just try and get a full write lock? It'll fail if anyone else has it open for reading or writing.</strike>

```
fopen("myfile.txt", "r+")
```

If it's not cross platform and is Win32, then you can request even more fine-grained set of locks.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858.aspx)
and look at `dwShareMode`, value of 0, as well as the other parameters.

Comment: Completely operating system dependent.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. Unless other application uses advisory locks.

See http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/816-0213/6m6ne37v5?a=view

Answer (score 0):

Non-natively, you could call out to [Sysinternals' handle.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx) as a last resort...

Comment: +1 I've been looking for an app which does exactly what handle.exe does. Thanks ZombieSheep.

Answer (score 0):

As @Neil Butterworth says, the standard library doesnt.

In unix you can use [fcntl](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/fcntl.h.html) to use file locks.

You could write a wrapper for your open function, that checks for a lock (and locks if none exists) a file if its open by no one else. You shold write a wrapper for close as well, that releases that lock on file close.

Comment: Locking is purely advisory, so this only tells you if somebody else has flocked the file.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing you have tagged linux -> there's a command-line too and API that have been added to the Linux kernel and do just that: [inotify](https://github.com/inotify-tools/inotify-tools).

Here's the [man](https://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify) page.

Answer (score -1):

In Windows this little and **dirty** trick will work (if the file exists and you have the right permissions)

```
  if (  0 != rename("c:/foo.txt", "c:/foo.txt")  ) {
     printf("already opened\n");
  }
```

It's likely to work also in Linux.

Comment: I could easily imagine someone adding a "fix" to an os in the future that broke this trick.

Comment: In linux, you can rename the file while it's open. The files are tracked by inode, not name. You can even delete the file, and the process that has it open will keep reading it without errors.

Comment: In the Explorer, you can also rename files that can't be removed because they are locked. Very useful when you want to copy files over existing ones, and can't overwrite a locked file.

Comment: really really dirty :) and we get false info about opened file when we have not rights to rename this :P