# How would I know that file is opened and it is saved after some writing operation using C code?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, filesystems, atomic

I have a set of configuration files (10 or more), and if user opens any of these file using any editor (e.g vim,vi,geany,qt,leafpad..). How would I come to know that **which file is opened** and if some writing process is done, then it is **saved or not** (using **C** code).

Comment: This sounds like you're trying to reinvent [system auditing](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/security_guide/chap-system_auditing).

Comment: read about `inotify`. But +1 for Andrew answer.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewHenle , but my main motive is to provide atomicity to few files,like if in case of power failure, while i am writing a file ,then my file should not get corrupted... how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

For the 1st part of your question, please refer e.g. to [How to check if a file has been opened by another application in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048592/how-to-check-if-a-file-has-been-opened-by-another-application-in-c) 
One way described there is to use a system tool like [lsof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lsof) and call this via a  `system()` call.

For the 2nd part, about knowing whether a file has been modified, you will have to create a backup file to check against. Most editors already do that, but their naming scheme is different, so you might want to take care of that yourself. *How to do that?* Just automatically create a (hidden) file `.mylogfile.txt` if it does not exist by simply copying `mylogfile.txt`. If `.mylogfile.txt` exists, is having an older timestamp than `mylogfile.txt`, and differs in size and/or hash-value (using e.g. `md5sum`) your file was modified.

But before re-implementing this, take a look at [How do I make my program watch for file modification in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931093/how-do-i-make-my-program-watch-for-file-modification-in-c/)